# Spring-boot. Create and bind table by request

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I use Spring boot and JPA/Hibernate implementation.
I have 2 table types:

1. ModelPool - the list of all models (there is only 2 fields: id and
   name)
2. Model - the dicription of the model (there are millions of rows for the particular model with some columns, and id as primary
   key)

By some event the application creates new model and it adds to the ModelPool table. So there has to be 1 modelPool table and some amount of model tables.

It's totally understood how to create 2 extra-large tables but this solution is not suitable because of poor performance.

I can't find the way to create new table dynamicaly by request and how to bind this new table to the appcontext bean's pool.

Now I'm looking to JPA @Query to make sql-query by myself but I still don't know how to bind the new table with the model bean.

Maybe this issue is tipycal and there is typical solution?

### **UPDATED:**

```
@Entity (name = "trackers") 
public class Tracker implements Serializable, Comparable<Tracker> {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;
@Column
private String number;
@Column (name = "devID")
private String devID;
@Column (name ="creationtimestamp")
private long creationTimestamp;
@Column
private double lon;
@Column
private double lat;

public Tracker() {
    this.creationTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Tracker that) {
    return Long.compare(this.creationTimestamp, that.creationTimestamp);
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public String getDevID() {
    return devID;
}

public void setDevID(String devID) {
    this.devID = devID;
}

public long getCreationTimestamp() {
    return creationTimestamp;
}

public void setCreationTimestamp(long creationTimestamp) {
    this.creationTimestamp = creationTimestamp;
}

public double getLon() {
    return lon;
}

public void setLon(double lon) {
    this.lon = lon;
}

public double getLat() {
    return lat;
}

public void setLat(double lat) {
    this.lat = lat;
}
}
```

---

```
@Service
public class TrackerService {
@Autowired
private TrackerRepository repository;

public void save(Tracker tracker) {
    repository.save(tracker);
}

public List<Tracker> getAll() {

    return StreamSupport
            .stream(
                    Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(repository.findAll().iterator(), Spliterator.NONNULL),
                    false)
            .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

}

---

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/avlan_db?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=****
spring.datasource.password=****
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Comment: show us some code to see what have you tried and see how we can help you out if you bump into some issue

Comment: @sfat, updated. But it's all from the manual nothing special. There must be solution not binded to particular case.